# Генерируемые ссылки

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Имеется страница такого рода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На ней из базы черпаются кол.во работ таким образом:

```
<table>

<tr>
    <td><p class="array">Наименование субъекта Российской Федерации</p></td>
    <td><p class="array">Количество работ</p></td>
</tr>

<?php
    include 'bd.php';

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT region, count(region) FROM `register_user` GROUP BY `region`");
    $array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    do
    {
    echo ""."<tr><td><p class='array'>".$array[region]."</p></td><td><p class='array'><a>".$array[count(region)]."</a></p></td></tr>"."";
    }
    while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($result));
?>

</table>
```

Как сделать числа у кол.ва работ ссылками на другие страницы? 
Они должны быть разными соответствующими своему региону.

То есть нажав на кол.во работ, мы получим информацию по работам в соответствующем регионе.

Answer (score 0):

вы не указали обязательный атрибут для ссылки "href"

Comment: То есть нужно указывать ссылку для каждого региона?

Comment: да <a href="/ссылка на регион/.$array['region'].">".$array[count(region)]."</a>

Comment: Это мне вряд-ли подойдет...
Так как таблица заполняется сама в соответствии с регионами, если добавилась работа, добавляется новый регион...

Comment: Возможно вы знаете какое-то альтернативное решение?
В конечном нажав допустим на байконур, мы должны получить вот такую страницу: https://imgur.com/a/iA4ta

С выборкой только по соответствующему региону.

Comment: в твоем случае тебе нужно создать страницу, где ты будешь получать из адресной страки прораметры,

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: Вот 2 страницы:

http://meowwiif.beget.tech/countreg.php
http://meowwiif.beget.tech/works.php

Может подскажите что и как сделать, огромное кол.во страниц создавать не вариант под каждую и прописывать вручную тоже, надо как-то упростить, а мозгов не хватает..

Comment: на странице с рег. и кол. работ ты должен сфоримировать ссылку к примкру  <a href="/region/.$array['region'].">".$array[count(region)]."</a>

Comment: где .$array['region']. должен быть уникален

Comment: потом делаешь страницу region.php в ней проверяешь $_GET['region'] tесли он есть то делаешь запрос в базу SELECT * FROM `register_user` where  `region` = $_GET['region']

Comment: Убило страницу.
https://imgur.com/a/KQ6Ct

Comment: запрос возвращает ошибку: https://imgur.com/a/X6Y0L